# Idiomatic alternative to the "putting yourself in one's shoe"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

Consider the expression,

> If the government **puts itself in the shoes of the public**, it will notice that its policies are damaging to society.

The construction "in one's shoe" sounds very awkward or old fashioned to me (I could be wrong about it being old fashioned though, however I don't see it being used in the American blog websites, I follow).

I can use the verb "project", but it feels out of place here. The government does not project, on its people's behalf.

Can somebody recommend a more idiomatic/natural construction?

Comment: It isn't so old-fashioned - see the examples [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-yourself-in-someones-shoes).

Comment: The government putting itself in the shoes of the public is a ***terrible*** use of metaphoric language! Just forget about it!

Comment: It's other people's **shoes**, plural, that we try to put ourselves in if we are attempting to empathise with people or see things from their point of view. Unless they have only one leg.